# Javascript Function - Goes to a new page

Tags: javascript, html, function

I currently have this:

```
<center><button onclick="ins()">Press Here For Instructions</button></center>
```

Followed by:

```
<script>
 function ins() {
document.write("(write instructions)")
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ins;
}
</script>
```

My issue is it goes to a new page when the function runs, how do i keep it on the same page?

Comment: Welcome. Could you please elaborate what you expect? Do you want the button not to disappear when the button is clicked?

Comment: I expect the button to stay, and the text to appear under the button on the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the element with id `demo` is a `div` and you want to set its content to `Press Here For Instructions` when the button is clicked; this should work for you:

```js
function ins() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "(write instructions)";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <button onclick="ins()">Press Here For Instructions</button>
  <div id="demo"></div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

//remove document.write dont use it 
//it is used for debugging purpose instead use console.log which doesnt affect your dom you can view the result in browser itself using F12 key

```
 <script>
     function ins() {  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ins;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, could you show an example?

Answer (score -1):

You should read what document.write does, e.g. here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

You are trying to change a already closed document, which will instead open a new one.

Comment: I added document.open(); and document.close(); still goes to a new page, unless im not understanding that website correctly?

Comment: The thing is that you most likely don't want to open a new document, neither explicitly with `document.open()`, nor implicitly with `document.write()`. As vahdet did state, you most likely wanted to do put a hint to your existing page.